# How to build a winui control library?

Tags: user-controls, winui-3

I want to make some custom user controls and share them in different applications. But I could find a project template or example to help do it.

There is a project template such as "WPF User Control Library" for WPF app, however I found no template for WINUI.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a class library for WinUI 3.

1. Create a new project
2. Class Library (WInUI 3 in Desktop)